# How create binary variable by comparison between row columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have this column of months in my data table that show the consecutive intervals of months.

```
> data[,"PromoInterval"]
          PromoInterval
     1: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
     2: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
     3: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
     4: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
     5: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
    ---                
324322: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
324323: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
324324: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
324325: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
324326: Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
```

Then I want to check if the date given below is in the corresponding interval assuming that each row of all the base was given in the same year.

The date column is:

```
> data[,"Date"]
              Date
     1: 2015-07-31
     2: 2015-07-30
     3: 2015-07-29
     4: 2015-07-28
     5: 2015-07-27
    ---           
324322: 2013-01-05
324323: 2013-01-04
324324: 2013-01-03
324325: 2013-01-02
324326: 2013-01-01
```

For example  I need to know if the date  **2015-07-31** of the first row is in the interval **Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct** given by the first row of the **PromoInterval** variable.

So I create a new variable result that convert the month given by the **Date** variable to his real noun:

```
data[,resultat:=as.character(month(ymd(010101) + months((data[,DateMonth])-1),label=TRUE,abbr=TRUE))]

> data[,"resultat"]
        resultat
     1:  juil\\.
     2:  juil\\.
     3:  juil\\.
     4:  juil\\.
     5:  juil\\.
    ---         
324322:  janv\\.
324323:  janv\\.
324324:  janv\\.
324325:  janv\\.
324326:  janv\\.
```

But I don't know why the format was like this above ?

Then I create a list that make **PromoInterval** as list type for each row:

```
data[,list:=strsplit((data[,PromoInterval]),split=',',fixed=TRUE)]
```

Then I compare if the month's name given by the **resultat** column does exist in the variable **list**. For example if the `juil` of the first row of `resultat` is in `Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct` given by the first row of `PromoInterval`.

So I create this binairy variable :

```
data[,Promoinsales:=if(resultat %in% list) {1} else {0}]
```

But the result was all null and not correct because the first row should be 1 not 0!(`7->Jul` exist in the list `Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct`)

```
> data[,"Promoinsales"]
        Promoinsales
     1:            0
     2:            0
     3:            0
     4:            0
     5:            0
    ---             
324322:            0
324323:            0
324324:            0
324325:            0
324326:            0
```

How do I resolve this please?
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dat[,promoinSales:=as.numeric(grepl(month.abb[month(Date)],PromoInterval)),by=1:nrow(dat)][] 
   nrow       Date   PromoInterval promoinSales
1:    1 2015-06-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct            0
2:    2 2015-05-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct            0
3:    3 2015-04-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct            1
4:    4 2015-01-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct            1
5:    5 2015-10-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct            1
6:    6 2015-12-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct            0

dat[,promoinSales:=as.numeric(grepl(format(as.Date(Date),"%b"),PromoInterval)),by=1:nrow(dat)][]
```

Data:

```
dat=fread("     Date PromoInterval
      2015-06-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
      2015-05-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
      2015-04-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
      2015-01-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
      2015-10-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
     2015-12-27 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
      ",sep=" ")
```

Comment: thank you for your proposition but it gives a column of zero !!

Comment: What does `dat[1,as.numeric(grepl(format(Date,"%b"),PromoInterval))]` give?

Comment: it gives zero : `> data[1,as.numeric(grepl(format(Date,"%b"),PromoInterval))]
[1] 0`

Comment: And is the date for the first row included?  ie `grepl(format(dat$Date,"%b"),dat$PromoInterval)`. If this is `FALSE` then that means the month you are lookin at is not included within Jan,April,Jun,Oct

Comment: you would do what by `any(grepl(format(as.Date(Date),"%b")` because if you want to extract the month number from the date I think that it should be `as.numeric(strftime(Date, format="%m"))`

Comment: what is the output of: `grepl(format(dat$Date[1],"%b"),dat$PromoInterval[1])` or `grepl(month.abb[month(dat$Date[1])],dat$PromoInterval[1])` Which of this gives you the expected results?

Comment: `> grepl(format(data$Date[1],"%b"),data$PromoInterval[1])
[1] FALSE`

Comment: here is the mistake `> format(data$Date[1],"%b")
[1] "juil."` look carefuly what it gives! It's `juil.` and not `Jul`. How can I correct it?

Comment: Which language is that set to? Mine gives `Jul`. okay what about  `month.abb[month(dat$Date[1])]`

Comment: when I download R I used the french language! ah  `> month.abb[month(data$Date[1])]
[1] "Jul" `.  I think this is the correct one! But how should I modify the code

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some headstart to solve this.

```
## this function checks if month name is present in PI
check_values <- function(x,y)
{
    y_val <- unlist(strsplit(y, split = ','))
    if(x %in% y_val) return(1)
    else return (0)
}

## add column in df2 since both df have same rows
df2[, PI := df1$PromoInterval]

## extract month from Date column
df2[, month_name := months(as.Date(Date), abbreviate = T)]

## get result
df2[, result := mapply(check_values, month_name, PI)]

## first few rows of output

         Date month_name              PI result
1: 2015-07-31        Jul Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct      1
2: 2015-07-30        Jul Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct      1
3: 2015-07-29        Jul Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct      1
4: 2015-07-28        Jul Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct      1
5: 2015-07-27        Jul Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct      1
```

Comment: thank you for your effort but the **month_name** gives  `juil.` and not `Jul`